# How to update text in pysimplegui

Tags: python

I'm very new to python so I'm just experimenting with new GUIs and other things. I was wondering if you could open up a window using pysimplegui and have a piece of text which says "0", and when you click a button the text changes to the previous number +1.
For E.G: at first the text says "0", but when you click a button of some sort, the text changes to a "1".
Sorry if my explanation of my problem is bad but I have not used stack overflow before.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
num = 0

layout = [
    [sg.Text(num)],
    [sg.Button("hi")]
]

window = sg.Window("the box", layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == "hi":
        num = num+1
        layout = [
    [sg.Text(num)],
    [sg.Button("hi")]
    ]
    window = sg.Window("the box", layout)
```

I tried this code but it did not work. As you can probably see I am very new to all of this so kindly do not type an answer with complicated/advanced code.

Thanks to tim who gave me an answer but i do not understand it, here is the new(still faulty) code:

```
    import PySimpleGUI as sg
num = 0

layout = [
    [sg.Text(key='xxx')],
    [sg.Button("hi")]
]

window = sg.Window("the box", layout)

while True:
    event, values['xxx'] = window.read()
    if event == "hi":
        xxx = num
        num = num + 1
```

Comment: When you get an event, the `values` you get passed has a dictionary of all of your UI elements.  If you add `key='XXX'` to your Text element, you can use `values['XXX']` to fetch that element and modify it.

Comment: Hi Tim. I do not understand exactly what you mean but I will try to implement this into my code, thank you for the comment though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should call method `window[element_key].update(value=new_value)` to update the element `window[element_key]` with new value `new_value`.

New layout and new window are not required.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

num = 0

layout = [
    [sg.Text(num, key='xxx')],
    [sg.Button("hi")],
]

window = sg.Window("the box", layout)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == "hi":
        num += 1
        window['xxx'].update(num)

window.close()
```